# shopify ajax clear cart

Tags: jquery, shopify

I am not to familiar with AJAX/Javascript so I am having a hard time doing something simple.

I am trying to clear the cart using [Shopify's AJAX API](http://docs.shopify.com/support/your-website/5-themes/can-i-use-ajax-api) before someone adds an item to the cart.

My code currently looks like this:

```
<script>
  function clearcart(){
    var my_button=$('input.addToCart');
    my_button.on('click',function(){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/cart/clear.js',
        data: '',
        success: success,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function() {
          return Shopify.clear();
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
          /* error code */
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
  }
</script>
<input type="submit" name="add" value="Try Now" class="addToCart" onclick="clearcart();" "javascript:window.location='/cart' return false"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try updating your code to this:

```
<script>
  function clearcart(){
    var my_button=$('input.addToCart');
    my_button.on('click',function(){
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/cart/clear.js',
        data: '',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function() {
          Shopify.clear();
        },
        error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
          /* error code */
        }
      });
      return false;
    });
  }
</script>
<input type="submit" name="add" value="Try Now" class="addToCart" onclick="clearcart();" "javascript:window.location='/cart' return false"/>
```

Changes:

- Removed `success: success,` line.
- Removed the `return` keyword in the `success` function.

Answer (score 0):

Actually `Shopify.clear()` does the AJAX call for you. So all you really need to do is:

```
function clearCart() {
  Shopify.clear();
}
```

In your form you have onclick="clearCart();" which will invoke that function for you.

I see you are doing some stuff with your window.location and if you wanted you could also do that within your clearCart function by leveraging the callback that can be passed into the `Shopify.clear` function call:

```
function clearCart() {
  Shopify.clear(function(){
    window.location = "/cart";
  });
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This seems to work for Firefox but not safari or chrome? any ideas? Is it because by doing this it doesn't wait for a ajax response?

Comment: I was executing the commands in Chrome, so the function should be working. Alternatively, you have access to jQuery I believe and you could perhaps attach an event listener to the DOM node you want to trigger this function with (Add to Cart)

Answer (score 0):

Use this for clear all data from cart page

```
$('.addToCart').click(function(){
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/cart/clear.js',
    data: '',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function() { 
      location.reload();
    },
    error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus) {
      /* error code */
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```